# I need to change one table datatype same as other in netezza, by just passing table name?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have one table named `L0` which is created as:

```
create table L0 (
   name varchar,
   number varchar,
   address varchar
);
```

The data type for all the columns present in `L0` is `varchar`,

I have another table `L1` which is created as:

```
create table L1 (
   name varchar,
   number int,
   address char
);
```

I want to convert the data types of `L0` table to be same as `L1` table, by just passing the table name.

I want the final query look like this:

```
select cast(name as varchar), cast(number as int), cast(address as char) from L0
minus
select * from L1:
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: Not clear. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [group_concat](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W9363c60167c7_4e4b_a188_a8bad09b7861/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples) UDA installed in Netezza then you can  get the desired output using `columns` metadata view

```
create table L0 (
   name varchar(20),
   number varchar(10),
   address varchar(50)
);

create table L1 (
   name varchar(50),
   number int,
   address char(20)
);
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT 'select ' || system..group_concat('cast (' || a.column_name || ' as ' || b.data_type || ')') || ' from ' || a.table_name || ' minus select ' || system..group_concat(b.column_name) || ' from ' || b.table_name || ' ;'
FROM columns a
    ,columns b
WHERE a.column_name = b.column_name
    AND a.table_name = 'L0'
    AND b.table_name = 'L1'
    AND a.table_catalog = 'TEST' --- this is the current database name 
GROUP BY a.table_name
    ,b.table_name;
```

**Output:**

```
    SELECT cast(ADDRESS AS CHARACTER(20))
    ,cast(NAME AS CHARACTER VARYING(50))
    ,cast(NUMBER AS INTEGER)
FROM L0 minus

SELECT ADDRESS
    ,NAME
    ,NUMBER
FROM L1;
```

**EDIT:**
Alternate approach using **stored procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GRP_CONCAT(varchar(50),varchar(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(ANY)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    TABLE_NAME1 ALIAS FOR $1;
    TABLE_NAME2 ALIAS for $2;
    return_text varchar(10000) := 'SELECT';
    x record;
BEGIN
FOR x IN    select a.column_name as colname,b.data_type datatype
FROM columns a
    ,columns b
WHERE a.column_name = b.column_name
    AND a.table_name = TABLE_NAME1
    AND b.table_name = TABLE_NAME2
    order by b.ordinal_position
    LOOP
    return_text := return_text || ' CAST ('||x.colname ||' as '||x.datatype||') , ';

    end loop;



     return_text := trim(return_text,' , ')||' FROM '||TABLE_NAME1 || ' minus select * from  '||TABLE_NAME2||';';

     return return_text;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: %', SQLERRM;
RETURN 1;
END;

END_PROC;
```

**Output :**

**Call GRP_CONCAT('L0','L1') ;**

```
SELECT CAST(NAME AS CHARACTER VARYING(50))
    ,CAST(NUMBER AS INTEGER)
    ,CAST(ADDRESS AS CHARACTER(20))
FROM L0 minus

SELECT *
FROM L1;
```

Comment: hello group concat is not working in my system, can you please suggest any alternate way           thanks in advance

Comment: @gagansharma updated my answer using Netezza stored procedure